# Magento2.3: item count is not updating in category page

Tags: magento2.3, category-products, toolbar, product-listing

We have added some of the products in one of the category. When we go to that category page, the item count is not updating. It always showing **"1 Total Result"**. Please see the below screenshot once.

Could anyone please help me to resolve this?

Comment: Can u please run indexer:reindex command and check

Comment: which PHP version have to use ?

Comment: @NareshRupareliya, I did run it. Still having the issue

Answer (score 0):

Please look at this file

> vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/list/toolbar/amount.phtml

If you have added that in your custom theme here

> app/design/frontend/Vendor/Theme/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/list/toolbar/amount.phtml

Then please rename it with `amount1.phtml` and check if this thing fix your issue ? Then again revert that file name and try to dubug that file's code.

Hope this will help you!

Comment: Thanks. Yes we have file amount.phtml on our custom theme so that I have renamed the file as your suggestion. But after renaming the file, the item count is not visible at all.

Comment: After renaming that file did you cleared Magento cache ?